# Use a string as a char

Tags: c++

I have been given this definitions, the function should return what is in info->phrase. However info->phrase can contain a string in which case I can only make it return the first char on info->phrase. Is there a way to make a string compatible with the char type? I am new to c++.

```
struct rep_info {
   int   num;
   char *phrase;
};
```

I´ve tried few thing but get type errors, this was my latest attempt

```
char *phrase_info(rep_info info) {

   char text[std::strlen(info->phrase) + 1];
   text = info->phrase;
   return text;
}
```

Comment: `char text[strlen(info->phrase) + 1];` is an Automatic variable. It vanishes when it goes out of scope, leaving you returning a pointer to garbage.

Comment: Can you not `return info->phrase;`?

Comment: What if you return a `std::string` instead of  a pointer?

Comment: That only gives me the first char of info->phrase

Comment: If I use return info->phrase; it only returns the first letter

Comment: Now that I look closer, it won't give either: `info` isn't a pointer. You'd have to use `return info.phrase;` It will give you a pointer to the first character. If this isn't giving you the full string, either there is no second character, or you are printing the string out incorrectly. Either way, you have another bug. If you provide a [mcve] maybe we can help sort out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have been given these definitions, let's fix the problem with the current setup first. Looking at your function, you are trying to copy into this local array (incorrectly I might add), and return this local variable. There are a number of things wrong with this, including the syntax and the fact that the local variable is destroyed when the function exits.

If you just need to get the value of the phrase member variable, the simplest solution would be to just access the member variable directly and return it:

```
char *phrase_info(rep_info info) {
      return info.phrase; //since info is not a pointer, use the '.' accessor
}
```

If you mean to pass a pointer to the function, you would re-write it like this:

```
char *phrase_info(rep_info *info) {
   return info->phrase;
}
```

But it seems like you feel the need to copy the contents of `info->phrase` into a new memory space? If so, then you would do something like this where you first allocate new memory and return this buffer:

```
char *phrase_info(rep_info *info) {
   char *buf = new char[std::strlen(info->phrase) + 1];
   std::strcpy(buf,info->phrase); //copies info->phrase into buf
   return buf;
}
```

You would then need to use `delete` on the returned memory value to clean up the memory allocated by `new`, otherwise you will have a memory leak.

Overall, all the above solution would potentially solve the problem given some parameters you haven't made clear. To round this out, this should be written more like:

```
class rep_info {
private:
   int   num;
   std::string phrase;
public:
   rep_info(int n, std::string p) : num(n), phrase(p) {}

   std::string get_phrase() { return phrase; }

   // other functions
};

//later in the code
rep_info info(...);
info.get_phrase();
```

Ideally, you would wrap these member variables into their own object with corresponding member functions that can get and set these values. Moreover, for handling strings in C++, `std::string` is the preferred option for storing, copying, modifying, etc. strings over the older `char *` C-style string.